# How to export Orient DB(2.2.x) schema with Rest API?

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to export orient db (2.2.x) using Http API.

HTTP GET request to  http://localhost:2480/export/demo2

I need to export the database schema alone with the data in it. Need an advice to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot export a database using the REST api however you can return its schema by calling this url (don't forget to authenticate):

```
http://<server>:<port>/query/YourDatabaseName/sql/select expand(classes) from metadata:schema
```

Here's the docs:

OrientDB | [Querying the schema](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL.html#query-the-schema)

OrientDB | [REST API - Query](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html#get---query)

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply.